# SFML Objects In Header File

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm using SFML with c++ to try game development and I want to put my player functions in a new class, But i cant seem to use my player sprite object in my main.cpp file.

This Is My Header, Header.cpp and Main.cpp file:

Header:

```
#ifndef PLY_H
#define PLY_H
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Ply
{
public:
    Ply(); //Constructor
    Player; //sf::Sprite Object


};

#endif
```

Header.cpp file:

```
#include "Ply.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace std;
Ply::Ply()
{
sf::Texture Playertex;
if(!Playertex.loadFromFile("Gabe.jpg"))
{
    //Error code here
}
sf::Sprite Player;
Player.setTexture(Playertex);

}
```

And main.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Ply.h"
int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800,800),"Game");
Ply ply;






while(window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while(window.pollEvent(event))
    {
       if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
       {
           window.close();
       }
       if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
       {
           ply.Player.move(sf::Vector2f(0,-5));
       }
       if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
       {
           ply.Player.move(sf::Vector2f(0,5));
       }
       if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
       {
           ply.Player.move(sf::Vector2f(-5,0));
       }
       if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
       {
           ply.Player.move(sf::Vector2f(5,0));
       }
       if(sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left))
       {
           sf::Vector2i MsLoc = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
           ply.Player.setPosition(MsLoc.x,MsLoc.y);
       }


    }

window.clear();
window.draw(ply.Player);
window.display();
}


return 0;
}
```

In the console it says "ply is not a class or namespace"

Help?

Comment: In your class definition (Ply.h) `Player; //sf::Sprite Object` has no type, try: `sf::Sptite Player;`

Comment: @Galik When I add sf::Sprite it builds but my sprite doesn't appear. I think it creates a new blank sprite object without the texture on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you creat a new, local `sf::Sprite` object and load the texture into that instead of the class member `sf:Sprite` of the same name:

```
Ply::Ply()
{
    if(!Playertex.loadFromFile("Gabe.jpg"))
    {
        //Error code here
    }
    sf::Sprite Player; // This is NOT the sf::Sprite in your class!!
    Player.setTexture(Playertex);

}
```

Just remove it and that should fix your problem:

```
Ply::Ply()
{
    sf::Texture Playertex;
    if(!Playertex.loadFromFile("Gabe.jpg"))
    {
        //Error code here
    }

    Player.setTexture(Playertex);

}
```

At least it will when you give your member `sf::Sprite` a type:

```
class Ply
{
public:
    Ply();

    sf::Sprite Player; // Needed a type!
    sf::Texture Playertex; // this also needs to be a member

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Galik spot one of the mistakes of your code. Another one is related to [the white square problem](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/graphics-sprite.php#the-white-square-problem). Basically, your texture is destroyed when you exit the constructor of `Ply`. You need to have the texture as a field of the class instead of a local variable.